# angular 2 data polluted between duplicate components?

Tags: javascript, angular

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here, but when I declare two components like this:

```
<todo-component [options]="selectOptions" [choice]="slideToggleSelection" (choiceChange)="handle($event)" group="weird">
</todo-component>

<todo-component [options]="selectOptions2" [choice]="slideToggleSelection2" (choiceChange)="handle($event)" group="test">
</todo-component>
```

... changing the value of one affects the value of the other. Check out this [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/MRWe41Z5dYJ2QdhPxJwX/) for an example. -- for instance, selecting 'Y' in one actually selects them in both. I think I'm misunderstanding some fundamental concept but I'm banging my head against the wall on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is related to the `[attr.name]="group"`. If you change it to `[name]="group"` it seems to work.

Comment: It would be great.. if you can you explain why this happened? +1

Comment: I really don't know. :-( The input tag does have a name attribute; the attr.name just seemed weird to me. Maybe a copy paste error? But this does not explain the behavior. To that I'm also clueless, sorry. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: it didn't work removing it entirely but it did changing it from `attr.name` to just `name`. thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is, that radio inputs with the same name belong to a radio group. Hence the name attribute had no value, they all belonged to the same group. And because the radio buttons with y also shared the value, they were sharing the same checked status?!